# How to send an incomplete http request using netcat?

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest, netcat

I'd like to send a incomplete http request, or some kind of request that will temporarily block my server for a while. I wrote the server myself in C, and it is currently designed to only accept one client at a time. I want to test that this is indeed the case.

Would it be possible to send something simple, similar to GET /HTTP/1.0? I'm just doing all my testing in my terminal, not using anything else so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with netcat.

```
nc -c servername 80 <<<"GET / HTTP/1.0"
```

This will send the `GET` line and then wait for the server to respond. But the server should be waiting for headers and the blank line that ends them, so it will never respond. So `nc` will wait forever, keeping the connection open.